# Java Method in Method in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, methods

I was searching several documents for getting answers but I couldn't.

What I want to code is "Methods in Method". Below is example in java8 (Stream API)

```
private static int sumStream(List<Integer> list) {
    return list.stream().filter(i -> i > 10).mapToInt(i -> i).sum();
}
```

In that codes, list call stream() method, stream() method called filter() method , mapToInt() method called sum() and return.

How can I code like this pattern?? Or, could you tell me search word in google or example codes please?

Comment: Google "java streams lambdas". But understand that questions such as this ... should not be asked here. So please spend some time at the [help] to learn how/what to ask here.

Comment: _"list call stream() method, stream() method called filter() method "_ -- No, that's not how it works.  `list.stream()` returns a `Stream` object.  Then that `Stream` object's method `filter()` is invoked. That returns a different `Stream`.  Then that new `Stream`'s `mapToInt()` is invoked, returning yet another new `Stream`.  Finally, the terminal operation `sum()` is invoked on that third `Stream`, returning an `int`.

Comment: @GhostCat Actually I read some documents about Java8 Lambda Hello world, but I didn't understand exactly :( I will study harder.. sorry.

Comment: @JimGarrison Thank you for making me understand!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are referring to chaining of method calls. This can be achieved when the methods of a class return the instance on which they were called.

For example:

```
public class A {
    public A foo () {
        // do something
        return this;
    }
    public A bar () {
        // do something
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then you can chain the method calls:

```
A a = new A();
a.foo().bar().foo();
```

Comment: Oh, returning class itself.. OK... I will think more! Thank you.

Comment: @Seung-RokBaek Not returning the class, returning an instance (object) of the class. Of course the chaining can also be achieved by returning instances of other classes (which would allow you to chain methods calls of different classes).